# Ending JQuery Event Bubbling

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-animate, jquery-events

This is really simple... but for some reason, I can't get it to work.
The JQuery below simply animates the background for the selections on a sideNav bar via click.
However, if I we're to click on multiple items within the half/second span more than one of the items would have the animation happen.  *(thus looking like multiple items are selected at once.)*

The `event.stopPropogation();` Is supposed to cancel the animation event, is it not?
If not, how can I fix this?

```
$('.sidebar nav ul li').not('.user').click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
    
  $('.sidebar nav ul li').css('background-size', '15px');
  $('.sidebar nav ul li').removeClass('active');
    
  $(this).animate({
'background-size': '100%'
  }, 500);

  setInterval(function(){
$(this).addClass('active');
    return true;
  },501);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stopPropagation` does exactly what it sounds like, it stops events from propagating up to the parent elements higher up in the DOM.
It does not stop animations, that would be `stop()`;

```
$('.sidebar nav ul li').not('.user').click(function(){

    $('.sidebar nav ul li').stop(true, true)
                           .css('background-size', '15px')
                           .removeClass('active');

    $(this).animate({
      'background-size': '100%'
    }, 500, function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: So obvious.  Thanks for your help!  That worked.  I try my best not to use JQuery Animations with CSS3 now, and it really just threw me for a loop.

Answer (score 2):

If it's an animation, you should prefer event.stop() to event.stopPropagation(). Hope it helps..